# Почему код выдаёт координаты не моего местоположения, а совсем другое?

Tags: javascript, карты, геолокация, координаты

```js
function coordinateUser() {
    var writeCoord = document.getElementById('coord'); //получение элемента сайта
    var msg = 'Координаты отсутствуют.';
    console.log(navigator.geolocation);

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
        writeCoord.textContent = 'Определение местоположения..';
        localStorage.setItem('navigator.geolocation', 'true');
    } else {
        writeCoord.textContent = msg;
        localStorage.setItem('navigator.geolocation', 'false');
    }

    function success(position) {
        var lat = (position.coords.latitude).toFixed(8);
        var lon = (position.coords.longitude).toFixed(8);
        var accuracy = position.coords.accuracy;
        msg = `${lat}, ${lon} <br>погрешность(в метрах): ${accuracy}`;
        writeCoord.innerHTML = msg;
    }
    function error(msg) {
        writeCoord.textContent = msg;
        console.log(msg.code);
    }
}
coordinateUser();
```

Comment: А на чём ты это проверяешь?

Comment: Проверял на яндекс.Карты и гугл мапс, результат один и тот же

Comment: На каком устройстве? На компьютере/ноутбуке обычно банально неоткуда взять информацию о положении, в них нет GPS.

Comment: Пробовал на компьютере,подключенном к сети wifi, выдавал совсем не те координаты, что нужны мне. А вот ноутбук, подключённый к той же сети выдавал координаты нужные

Comment: Браузеры и OS одинаковые? Тот же гугл или яндекс могут точнее угадывать ваше местоположение по косвенным признакам, но в  общем случае на компе без GPS хорошо если город по IP можно угадать.